# How can we do multi-point warping in opencv

Tags: perspective, homography, warp

Usually we use 4 points for correcting perspective of an image. How can we use more number of points to convert a very distorted edged rectangle into a straight rectangle in opencv. Basically I'm trying to warp an image with a piece of cloth. The cloth edges are not straight. Illustrated through the following image[image]

Comment: hi Sum-ai  can you find a way to do it ?

Comment: Hi, yes, try something called "Affine Transformation"